# Parse Google Drive File to custom object

Tags: android, google-drive-api

How can we parse the file received from Google Drive API to the original uploaded file.

I upload a json file that contains List and receives only a json file that contains the id name and metadata. How can I get the orginal json from that file.

```
 val contentStream = ByteArrayContent.fromString("application/json", notesJson)
                val file: File =
                    googleDriveService.files().create(metadata, contentStream)
                        .setFields("id")
                        .execute()
```

This is what I receive

```
{"id":"1cX1W7x5yomyyvzRYwY","kind":"drive#file","mimeType":"application/json","name":"backup.json"}
```

Comment: When you create a file using drive api. It will return a [File Resource object](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files#resource). If you want to download a drive file to see its content you can refer to this reference [Download a file stored on Google Drive](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/manage-downloads?hl=en#download_a_file_stored_on_google_drive)

Comment: Thank you, just figured it now